# Find and rename multiple files using a bash script in Linux

Tags: bash, file-rename, batch-rename

As an example, in a directory `/home/hel/files/` are thousends of files and hundreds of directories.
An application saves there its output files with special characters in the file names.
I want to replace these special characters with underscores in all file names. e.g. `-:"<>@`

I wrote a bash script which simply repeats a command to rename the files using Linux/Unix 'rename'.

Example: file name: `rename.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
rename "s/\'/_/g" *
rename 's/[-:"<>@\,&\s\(\)\[\]?!–~%„“;│\´\’\+#]/_/g' *
rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *
rename 's/\.(?=[^.]*\.)/_/g' *
rename 's/[_]{2,}/_/g' *
```

I execute the following find command:

```
find /home/hel/files/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -execdir /home/hel/scripts/rename.sh {} \+
```

Now the issue:

This works fine, except the fact, that it renames subdirectories too, if they have the searched characters in their name.

The find command searches just for files and not for directories.

I tried some other find variations like:

```
find /home/hel/files/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -execdir sh /home/hel/scripts/rename.sh {} \+
find /home/hel/files/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -execdir sh /home/hel/scripts/rename.sh {} +
find /home/hel/files/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -execdir sh /home/hel/scripts/rename.sh {} \;
```

They are all working, but with the same result.

What is not working:

```
find /home/hel/files/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sh /home/hel/scripts/rename.sh {} \+
```

This one is dangerous, because it renames the directories and files in the current directory, where you call the find command too.

Maybe one has an idea, why this happens or has a better solution.

Comment: In your script for renaming the file put a test to check if the input is a file.  `[[ -f filename ]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script `rename.sh` did not use its command line arguments at all, but instead searched files and directories (!) on its own using the glob `*`.

Change your script to the following.

```
#!/bin/bash
rename -d s/\''/_/g;
s/[-:"<>@\,&\s\(\)\[\]?!–~%„“;│\´\’\+#]/_/g;
y/A-Z/a-z/;
s/\.(?=[^.]*\.)/_/g;
s/[_]{2,}/_/g' "$@"
```

Then use `find ... -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sh .../rename.sh {} +`.

#### Changes Made

- Use `"$@"` instead of `*` to process the files given as arguments rather than everything in the current directory.
- Execute `rename` only once as a 2nd `rename` wouldn't find the files specified with `"$@"` after they were renamed by the 1st `rename`.
- Use the `-d` option such that only the basenames are modified. `find` always puts a path in front of the files, at the very least `./`. Without this option `rename` would change `./filename` to `mangledPath/newFilename` and therefore move the file to another directory.

Note that `man rename` is a bit misleading

```
--path, --fullpath
        Rename full path: including any directory component.  DEFAULT

-d, --filename, --nopath, --nofullpath
        Do not rename directory: only rename filename component of path.
```

For a given path `rename -d 's...' some/path/basename` just processes the `basename` and ignores the leading components `some/path/`. If `basename` is a directory it will still be renamed despite the `-d` option.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer.
I tried out your suggestions.

I replaced the "*" with "$@" in the rename.sh script and it really works for solving the issue, that directories are not renamed, but I need to repeat the whole command again and again until it completes the replacements.
For 200 test files I did about 15 manual repeats. Error messages saying, that the currently changed file is not available. I think, after changing one part of the file name replacement, the next step couldn't find the file, due to it different name.

Comment: @Helmut If you just replaced each of your five `*` with `$@` then you guessed correctly. However, there shouldn't be any problems with the script I posted (and I was wrong in writing *`the rest is just for efficiency`*). In the script from this answer, there is only one `rename` command inside `rename.sh` that does all the renaming steps internally instead of actually renaming the files for each step.

Comment: I highly appreciate your answer. Your script is working fine after two modifications. I use the UTF8 literals for replacing the single quote character. It is:  `rename 's/\x27/_/g;`. The other modification is to use instead of -execdir the -exec action. For now this was the only way to get the replacement of dots working. `s/\.(?=[^.]*\.)/_/;` With -execdir, find pipes the resulting filesnames with an ./ in the beginning, which the pattern is searching for. Maybe I'am wrong, but I'll find out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Helmut Oh right. I forgot that `find` prefixes everything with `./` even with `-execdir`. Glad I could help.